# Context is null in SignalR hub

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a Web Forms application and testing to see how SignalR works for one of my requirement.  My hub code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalRTest.Hubs
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public static readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();


        public NotificationHub()
        {
            var myInfo = Context.QueryString["myInfo"];

            _Timer.Interval = 2000;
            _Timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            _Timer.Start();
        }

        void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int i = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("NotificationHub");
            hub.Clients.All.Alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

My Client call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var logger = $.connection.notificationHub;
        logger.client.Alert = function (msg) {
            if (msg == 1) {
                $("#HyperLink1").show();
                $("#HyperLink2").hide();

            }
            else {
                $("#HyperLink1").hide();
                $("#HyperLink2").show();
            }
        };

        $.connection.hub.qs = "myInfo=12345";
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

But, for some reason, when examined the Context on the server code (in hub), it is null, so I cannot retrieve the querystring value.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe the Context is available at the point the Hub is created. Instead you can override `OnConnection` on your Hub class:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var myInfo = Context.QueryString["myInfo"];

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Docs on [Hub Object Lifetime](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#transience):

> You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its methods from your own
>   code on the server; all that is done for you by the SignalR Hubs
>   pipeline. SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time
>   it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a client connects,
>   disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.
>
> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them
>   to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the
>   server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your
>   Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple
>   connections and method calls, use some other method such as a
>   database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class
>   that does not derive from Hub. If you persist data in memory, using a
>   method such as a static variable on the Hub class, the data will be
>   lost when the app domain recycles.

Comment: notificationsHub.server.setValue(12345); on client, this gives me an error.  'notificationsHub' is undefined

Comment: You've called your hub `notificationHub` not `notificationsHub` that's probably why. I've updated my answer with how you *can* retrieve the querystring value.

Comment: You are correct.  The Context will be null by the time it exits OnConnected.  I was able to retrieve the Query String value in the override.